# Prevent gVim from returning control to command line (when called from Stata)

Tags: vim, stata

When I call gVim from Stata with `shell` (or equivalently with `!`) Stata doesn't wait for the command to finish and continues on with the .do file. I usually specify a short `sleep` and everything works great (discussed on the Stata mailing list [here](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2002-06/msg00295.html)).

But sometimes the gVim call is lengthy and the length is unknown a priori. For example. I use gVim's `argdo` to remove headers from a folder of text files.

```
!gvim -c "argdo 1,3d | update" *sheet*.txt
```

Is there any way that I can force gVim to not return control to Stata? Or are my best options to complete this step outside the .do file or with a `pause`/lengthy `sleep`? Thanks!

Oh, I'm on Win 8 (64 bit) with gVim 7.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to make this call a Stata command or the equivalent thereof.

That is, try running this separately from a do-file editor window or as wrapped up in a separate do-file.

I realise that is not an attractive solution, but in principle it seems the only one.

(`sleep` solutions I dislike as fudges, but I guess no one likes them on principle.)

Comment: Thanks, Nick. This is what I've been doing, but once you have 99% automated you really hope there's a way to get that last bit.